# Can I receive value data from 2 Activities with SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

How can I receive values from 2 `Activities`, (passing data)?

I have 3 Activity, `ActivityOne`, `ActivityTwo`, `ActivityThree`. I want to send value(passing data) from `ActivityOne` to `ActivityThree`, and `ActivityTwo` to `ActivityThree`.

All data in `ActivityThree` not be destroy, so all value data from `ActivityOne` and `ActivityTwo` any in `ActivityThree`. Data from `ActivityOne` save temporary variable in `ActivityThree` and data from `ActivityTwo` save temporary variable in `ActivityThree` too. So I can show all values data from `ActivityOne` and `ActivityTwo` in `ActivityThree` together,

Can I make `SharedPreferences`? If yes, can any one provide an example?

Comment: of course shared preferences are always an option :http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref. but from the looks of it, seems like you're looking for the work of `intents`: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SharedPreferences is not a bad Idea but your requirement is temporary. So better you use Bundle Extras. Take Bundle object and pass all your first activity variables to Second Activity through bundle. Retrieve the bundle from the intent and put the second activity variables in the same bundle and pass the same to Third Activity. Retrieve the Bundle in Third Activity and use them. I hope this will help you.

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("name","value");
b.putInt("name1",9);
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtras("bundle",b);
startActivity(i);
```

retrieving in second activity

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundle"):
b.putString("namein2",value);
b.putInt("nameIntin2",8);
Intent i = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,ThirdActivity.class);
i.putExtras("bundle",b);
startActivity(i);
```

Retrieve the bundle and use it in Third Activity

Comment: but fill values in Activity1 continue to Activity2, i want fill the values free, first Activity1 or Activity2 no problem,

Comment: hey as per ur question the above answer is correct and i dont understand ur comment

Comment: i mean, i'm filling values from Activity1 or Activity2 is free, i can choose The first i'm filling Activity1 or Activity2. because i make menus to go to Activity1 or Activity2. or Activity3 for showing values   

i'm sorry i bad in english.

Comment: because when i fill in Activity1 and continue in Activity2, and continue in Activity3, i want i free go to Activity1, Activity2, or Activity3. with any menus that i make.

Comment: finally I understood ur requirement. You want to navigate between the screens freely. Ok then also you can use the above concept while you starting the other activities. Think peacefully on the concept I said, then you get an idea. you can over write the values as keys in bundle will remain unique.

Answer (score 0):

If you use shared preference,

```
    //Get shared preference
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("ANY_NAME_TO_IDENTIFY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //To set value
    pref.edit().putString("NAME", "Simone").commit();
    pref.putLong("NUMBER", new Date().getTime()); 

    //To get value

    pref.getString("NAME", "Put_any_default_value");
    pref.getLong("NUMBER", new Date().getTime());
```